# Grails App Deployed to 2 Servers behind Load Balancer - Spring Security clearCachedRequestmaps()

Tags: grails, spring-security

We have a Grails (1.3.7) application deployed to 2 web servers that are sitting behind a load balancer.  The problem we're seeing is that when we modify the RequestMaps the springSecurityService.clearCachedRequestmaps() only gets called on whatever server the user has a session to at that time.  So that cache isn't getting reset on the other server.

This causes issues when logging in with a connection to the other server and not having the correct permissions because of bad request map cache.  What is the right thing to do here?

One thought is to have a quartz job running that clears the cache every, say, 5 minutes.  But I'm not sure that is optimal.

Answer (score 0):

How about clearing it on login?

Comment: That's not a bad idea but I don't think it is much better than a Quartz job. It will still be resetting the cache too often.  We have another approach we're going to work on, and I'll update this with that if it works.  Ultimately, I think we need to look at session clustering though.

Answer (score 0):

How about a Filter then that does what ever you need once per session.